# how to set skeleton during getServerSideProps fetch request loading next js

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

Inside getServerSideprops and want to show loading state inside JSX so that I can add skeleton , or is there any other method to show skeleton without lag in route change?

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context: 
GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
const { errorCode, business,loading } = await fetch(
    url
)

return {
    props: {
        errorCode: errorCode || null,
        business: business || null,
    },
}
```

}

```
export default function Index(props:any){
if(props.loading){
 return <Skeleton/>

}
return <Content data={props.business}/>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show anything in ui until you get props to your Index component. What you should do is move the fetch code in useEffect inside the component.

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context: 
GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
return {};
}
```

```
export default function Index(props:any){
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [business, setBusiness] = useState({} as any);
const [errorCode, setErrorCode] = useState({} as any);

useEffect(() => {
    fetchCall();
},[]);

function fetchCall() {
    const { errorCode, business } = await fetch(url);
    setBusiness(business);
    setErrorCode(errorCode);
}

if(loading){
 return <Skeleton/>

}
return <Content data={business}/>
}
```

Comment: this does not support SSR

Comment: if we switch to ssr then until the request is completed user will not be able to see anything and blank page will continue loading, that's why we have to choose either ssr or skeleton

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use useState and useEffect in your component so when props will be sent to component it will trigger useEffect that will set loading to false.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
useEffect(()=>{
setLoading(false)},[])
```

And in your jsx you can simply handle it with terenary operator e.g

```
<div>
{isLoading ? <Skeleton /> : <div>Content</div>}
</div>
```